# Can you explain k-orbit polyhedra in a simple way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, group-theory, orbit-stabilizer

I am having a hard time understanding the concept of k-orbit polyhedra. What does "k" mean in the k-orbit polyhedra? Is it just the number of shapes/polygon within the polyhedra? or is it something else?

Comment: Have you seen for example "Two-Orbit_Convex_Polytopes_and_Tilings" by Nicholas Matteo available on Research Gate ?